# Keeping image and text together on one page in Google Docs using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am adding data from a Google Forms form to a Google doc.

Part of the form are a couple of images. I am successfully adding them to a Google doc and want to add a text label to describe the image. I am using this code snippet in a loop:

```
body.insertParagraph(indexOfStartElement++, value[0] + ": ");
body.insertImage(indexOfStartElement++, getImage(info[value[0]][0]));
```

Sometimes, the image and the label are not kept together on one page, like shown here:

[image]

How can I keep them together?

Comment: You can insert a page break before or after.